# Couldn't setMetdata on nft using Asset Hub

Tags: polkadot, nft, statemint, debug

This is Polkadot Punks #2 : https://kodadot.xyz/ahp/gallery/7-2

Accidentally i set Nft config of this nft to 6

```
{
  settings: 6
}
```

which in result dosen't allow me to setMetdata on it
how can i change nft config of this nft

[image: Screenshot of item setting derived from chainState]